# How to achieve multiple following-sibling's from an xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, siblings

Consider the following xpath with repeated following-sibling's:

```
//tr[td[text()='Map']]/td/following-sibling::td/following-sibling::td/preceding-sibling::td/text()", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)
```

It has the same result as a single following-sibling:

```
//tr[td[text()='Map']]/td/following-sibling::td/following-sibling::td/preceding-sibling::td/text()", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)
```

Apparently the repeated following-sibling's are treated as duplicates ..?  So then how to achieve the effect of "give me the third succeeding sibling" ?

thanks!

Comment: Your two examples seem to be the same?

Comment: I don't really understand the need for `..../td/following-sibling::td`, instead of `......./td[2]`. Does `//tr[td[text()='Map']]/td/following-sibling::td[3]/text()", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)` give you what you want? or, simpler, `//tr[td='Map']]/td[4]/text()", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following XML:

```
<tr>
    <td>Map</td>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Second</td>
    <td>Third</td>
</tr>
```

these XPaths (second by suggestion from @paul t.)

```
//tr/td[text()='Map']/following-sibling::td[3]/text()
//tr[td='Map']/td[4]/text()
```

return `'Third'` as expected.